# Call the same function by varying parameters with tidyverse and apply family functions

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

This is my first question here on Stack Overflow, so I apologize in advance if I won't be clear enough.
I searched for similar questions, but I didn't find anything (I probably didn't search enough!)

Given a `data.frame` (or a `data.table` or a `tibble`) consisting of four sets of points divided into two groups:

```r
df_points <- tibble(
    x = c(rnorm(10000, mean = 0), rnorm(10000, mean = 1), 
          rnorm(10000, mean = 0), rnorm(10000, mean = 4)), 
    dist = c(rep("d1", 10000), rep("d2", 10000), 
             rep("d1", 10000), rep("d2", 10000)), 
    overlap = c(rep("o1", 20000), rep("o2", 20000))
)
```

my goal is to apply the `density` function, using different values of `bw`, `from` and `to` for the `"o1"` and `"o2"` groups.

I would like to solve this problem in an elegant way with both a `tidyverse` and a `R-base`-`data.table` approach (`apply` family functions).

For now I have managed to do this via `tidyverse`:

1. I define a `common_dens` function which applies `density` and returns a tibble of the `x` and `y` of the distribution

   ```r
   common_dens <- function(df, Bw, lower, upper) {
     d <- density(df, n = 2048, bw = Bw, from = lower, to = upper)
     df_d <- tibble(x = d$x, y = d$y)
     return(df_d)
   }
   ```
2. assuming that the values of upper, lower and bws are the following:

   ```r
   lower <- c(-5.050, -4.705)
   upper <- c(6.445, 9.070)
   bws <- c(0.1427, 0.1417)
   ```

   I get the desired dataframe through the following `for` loop:

   ```r
   df_dens <- NULL
   for (i in 1:2) {
     df_t <- df_points %>% 
         filter(overlap == unique(df_points$overlap)[[i]]) %>% 
         group_by(dist, overlap) %>%
         summarise(common_dens(x, bws[i], lower[i], upper[i]))
     df_dens <- rbind(df_dens, df_t)
   }
   ```

Is there any way to remove the `for` loop?

Is there a way to do the same with `apply` family functions and `data.table`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `purrr::pmap` function allows you to apply an arbitrary number of parameters to a function in succession. The `pmap_dfr` returns a data.frame bound by row:

Consider your parameters provided as a data.frame:

```
params <- data.frame(group = c("o1","o2"), bws, lower, upper)
  group    bws  lower upper
1    o1 0.1427 -5.050 6.445
2    o2 0.1417 -4.705 9.070
```

The paramters are automatically assigned to the special symbols `..1`, `..2`, and so on:

```
library(purrr)
pmap_dfr(params, ~ df_points %>%
           filter(overlap == ..1) %>%
           group_by(dist, overlap) %>%
           summarise(common_dens(x,Bw = ..2, lower = ..3, upper = ..4)))
```

It can get confusing which `..#` is which, so a trick is to use `with(list(...), )`:

```
pmap_dfr(params, ~ with(list(...), df_points %>%
           filter(overlap == group) %>% 
           group_by(dist, overlap) %>% 
           summarise(common_dens(x,Bw = bws, lower = lower, upper = upper))))
```

---

You could of course do the same with base R apply:

```
apply(params, 1, function(y){ df_points %>%
        filter(overlap == y[1]) %>% 
        group_by(dist, overlap) %>% 
        summarise(common_dens(x, Bw = as.numeric(y[2]), lower = as.numeric(y[2]),
                              upper = as.numeric(y[4])))}) %>%
   bind_rows()
```

However, because `apply` converts the types, you'll need to use `as.numeric`.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply.

The method you propose with `pmap_dfr` is exactly what I was looking for! (`tidyverse` approach)

As for the method you propose with `apply`, there is a mix of approaches because pipe, `filter`, `group_by` and `summarise` functions are from the `tidyverse` (`dplyr`) package group. Do you know a way to do everything in `R-base`? (maybe `tapply`, but I don't know)

If you can improve the answer I would be very grateful, otherwise it is already very good!